# Google Datastore app architecture questions

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on a Google AppEngine app connecting to the Google Cloud Datastore via its JSON API (I'm using PHP).

I'm reading all the documentation provided by Google and I still have questions:

1. In the documentation about [Transactions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions), there is the following mention: "Transactions must operate on entities that belong to a limited number (5) of entity groups" (BTW few lines later we can found: "All Datastore operations in a transaction can operate on a maximum of twenty-five entity groups"). **I'm not sure about what is an entity group**. Let's say that I've an object Country which is identified only by its kind (COUNTRY) and a datastore's auto affected key id. So there is no ancestor path, hierarchical relationships, etc... Is all the countries entities counting for only 1 entity group? Or each country is counting for one?
2. For the Country entity kind I need to have an incremental unique id (like the SQL AUTOINCREMENT). It has to be absolutely unique and without gap. Also, this kind of object won't be created more than few / minute so there is no need to handle contention & sharding. I'm thinking about having a unique counter that will reflect the auto increment and using it inside a transaction. Is the following code pattern OK?: 
   `Starting transaction, getting the counter, commit the creation of the Country along with the update of the counter. Rollback the transaction if the commit fails.` Does this pattern prevents the affectation of 2 same ids? Could you confirm me that if 2 processes get the counter at the same time (so the same value), the first one who commits will make the other to fail (so it will be able to restart and get the new counter value)?
3. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Transactions_and_entity_groups) also mention that: "If your application receives an exception when attempting to commit a transaction, it does not necessarily mean that the transaction has failed. It is possible to receive exceptions or error messages even when a transaction has been committed and will eventually be applied successfully" !? How are we supposed to handle that case? If this behavior occurs on the creation of my country (question #2), I will have an issue with my auto increment id, no!?
4. Since the datastore needs that all the writes actions of a transaction to be done in only one call. And since the transaction ensure that all or none of the transaction's actions will be performed, why do we have to make a rollback?
5. Is the limit of 1 write / sec only on an entity (so something defined by its kind and its key path) and not a whole entity group (I will be reassured only when I'll be sure about what exactly is an entity group ;-) question #1)

I'm stoping here to not make a huge post. I'll probably get back with others (or refined) questions after getting answers on this ones ;-)

Thanks for your help.

[UPDATE] Country is just used as a sample class object.

Comment: This is not one question, there are at least five questions here.  Please ask them separately.

Comment: They're all about transactions and some are related to others. Anyway, I'll do it

Comment: Why do you want to have an incremental ID for a country? Why not to use country slug as an ID? Using counters for auto incrementing things.. you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Dmitry. I should have precise that, Country is just a sample class, I could have say Foo.

Comment: @BrentWashburne Ok, now I'm agree, I should have split every question... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, `('Country', 123123)` and `('Country', 679621)` are not in the same entity group. But `('Country', 123123, 'City', '1')` and `('Country', 123123, 'City', '2')` are in the same entity group. Entities with the same ancestor are in the same group.
2. Sounds like really bad idea to use auto-increment for things like countries. Just generate an ID based on the name of the country.
3. From the same paragraph:

> Whenever possible, structure your Datastore transactions so that the end result will be unaffected if the same transaction is applied more than once.

4. In internal datastore APIs like db or ndb you don't have to worry about rolling back, its happening automatically.
5. It's *about* 1 write per sec per whole entity group, that's why you need to keep groups as smaller as possible.

Comment: 1. That was my fear... So we have to keep to entity group as small as possible to not generate contention, but on the other hand if we want to use transactions we have to be careful about not having to much entity groups...

Comment: 2. Ok, but let's say I really need that. Is the described code pattern ok?

Comment: 3. Yes, I read the recommendation about making as much as possible idempotent actions, but in the case of the auto increment id, it sounds like a big issue...

Comment: 4. So what there is an API for that? Should I don't care about it?

Comment: The docs says that you MUST do a rollback, so just do it.Why do you need incremental ids? Its possible to achieve but only if you will have small amounts of writes per second.

Comment: There is no issue since there won't have a lot of writes per second. Just a few per hours, maximum...

Comment: Then make a counter, and make each `Foo` entity a child of this Counter. ('Counter', 'a', 'Foo', '1'). So you will keep al the `Foo` in the same entity group, so you can increment the counter each time you put new entity. Note that you should use "custom ID" for counter as you need to know the whole path of the entity to get it.